# Packery js shuffle and fit to container

Tags: jquery, html, css, packery

So I have a Packery grid, looking to shuffle items so that they perfectly organize at least to the height of the container...if the width is off, that's fine.

Looking at a layout like this:

```
<div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item grid-sizer"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x250" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x200" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x200" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x200" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" class="img-responsive" /></div>
    </div>
```

Some general styling:

```
.grid-sizer, .grid-item{
            width: 20%;
    float: left;

            img{
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }

        .grid-item--width2{
            width: 40%;
        }
```

Lastly, the initiator:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
$grid.packery({
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    gutter: 0,
    precentPosition: true
});
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/yfp841un/

Comment: well, you need to show us what have you tried so far & if possible create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes, my apologies, it's pretty open ended as I'm just trying to figure out how to get anything to work. Imagine, not all equal sizes, do I have to implement standards and specs for the result to render properly. Looking to fit into a box, one that I'm entertaining the idea of 100vh and then letting the width do whatever it wants. Again, these are not musts for the answer to be accepted, I'm flexible. To know how to shuffle them into the right spots, is going to be big as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've decided that without some additional jquery which I can write later if I want, there is going to have to be specs on uploads. It's impossible to avoid the gappage without it, if someone wants to blow my mind and show me, without using a stack of jQuery which I know it can be done then.

However, the shuffle, I did write up a piece, and then packery it back up, actually ends up doing pretty darn well most the time...still get some gaps until I standardize my specs though.

```
var $grid = $('.grid');
var $gridItems = $grid.children('.grid-item');

$gridItems.sort(function(a, b) {
var tmp = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
var isOddOrEven = tmp % 2;
var isPosOrNeg = tmp > 5 ? 1 : -1;
return (isOddOrEven & isPosOrNeg);
}).appendTo($grid);

shuffle($gridItems).appendTo($grid);

$('.grid').packery();

function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length,
temporaryValue, randomIndex;

// While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {

// Pick a remaining element...
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
currentIndex -= 1;

// And swap it with the current element.
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
}
```